# Invalid request. X-Goog-Upload-Command header is missing

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm running this code in Firebase Firestore and it gives the error:

> Invalid request. `X-Goog-Upload-Command` header is missing

```
if (task.isSuccessful()){
    Uri download_uri = task.getResult().getUploadSessionUri();
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code?

Comment: in firebase firestore 'Invalid request.  X-Goog-Upload-Command header is missing.' this problem